# Replacing a whole word and not substrings in a string in C

Tags: c, string, replace, cpu-word

I am trying to replace a whole word in C array of characters and skip the substrings. I made research and I ended up with really hard resolutions while I think I have better idea if someone can give me a hand.
Let's say I have the string:

```
char sentence[100]= "apple tree house";
```

And I would like to replace tree with the number 12:

```
"apple 12 house"
```

I know that the words are delimited by space so my idea is to :

1.Tokenize the string with delimiter white space
2.In the while loop checking with the library function STRCMP if the string is equal to the token and if it is then to be replaced.

The problem for me comes when I try to replace the string as I couldn't make it.

```
void wordreplace(char string[], char search[], char replace[]) {

  // Tokenize
  char * token = strtok(string, " ");

  while (token != NULL) {
    if (strcmp(search, token) == 0) {
      REPLACE SEARCH STRING WITH REPLACE STRING
    }
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
  printf("Sentence : %s", string);

}
```

Any suggestions what I can use ? I guess it might be really simple but I am beginner much appreciated :)
[EDIT]: Spaces are the only delimiters and usually the string to be replaced is not longer than the original.

Comment: One of the challenges here that is sort inextricable from the algorithmic aspect of this problem is the issue of memory management. C forces you to worry about this a lot, for example, what if replacing the words makes the string longer than it already was? Will you overrun allocated memory that the caller gave you? Do you know how much you have? If you're required to edit the same string you're given you can probably only do it in all cases by allocating a temporary string, too. You've not stated any particular parameters around the input-- e.g. are spaces the only whitespace that matters?

Comment: @BenZotto spaces are the only delimiters and the string to be replaced is not longer than the original one

Comment: In your edit, you say that the string is not longer than the original. Yet it is in your example of replacing "tree" with "banana". The new string is two characters longer than the original. And if the input was "tree tree tree" it would be six chars longer. Ie, unpredictable change in the size of the resulting output, which is a useful data point for you to work with. It tells you that this function alone, without further context about allocated string sizes, can't really work.

Comment: I am sorry it's my wrong I edited it :)  Thanks for mentioning it

Comment: Ah OK. That makes a substantial difference in how possible and easy the function can be, if you're only shrinking the input length, never expanding it.

Comment: If you're supposed to do an in-place replacement, then using strtok is probably a poor choice to start with, since it will modify the original string with newline characters.

Comment: `strtok()` is *always* a bad choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want to do becomes a little more involved because you need to handle the scenarios where:

1. replacement **is shorter than** original -- so you will need to move the remainder of line to follow the replacement text to avoid leaving empty space;
2. replacement **is same length** as original -- trivial case, just overwrite original with replacement; and finally
3. replacement **is longer than** original -- where you must validate the original string plus the replacement length difference will still fit in the storage for the original string, you must copy the end of line to a temporary buffer before making the replacement, and then add the rest of the line in the temporary buffer to the end.

`strtok` is some disadvantages here due to it making changes to the original string during the tokenizing process. (you can just make a copy, but if you want an in-place replacement, you need to look further). A combination of `strstr` and `strcspn` allow you to operate on the original string in more efficient manner when looking for a specific search string within the original.

`strcspn` can be used like `strtok` with the set of delimiters to provide the length of the current token found (to ensure `strstr` didn't match your search term as a *lesser-included-substring* of a longer word, like `tree` in `trees`) Then it becomes a simple matter of looping with `strstr` and validating the length of the token with `strcspn` and then just applying one of the three cases above.

A short example implementation with comments included in-line to help you follow along could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLIN 100

void wordreplace (char *str, const char *srch,
                    const char *repl, const char *delim)
{
    char *p = str;                      /* pointer to str */
    size_t  lenword,                    /* length of word found */
            lenstr = strlen (str),      /* length of total string */
            lensrch = strlen (srch),    /* length of search word */
            lenrepl = strlen (repl);    /* length of replace word */

    while ((p = strstr (p, srch))) {    /* srch exist in rest of string? */
            lenword = strcspn (p, delim);   /* get length of word found */
        if (lenword == lensrch) {       /* word len match search len */
            if (lenrepl == lensrch)     /* if replace is same len */
                memcpy (p, repl, lenrepl);  /* just copy over */
            else if (lenrepl > lensrch) {   /* if replace is longer */
                /* check that additional lenght will fit in str */
                if (lenstr + lenrepl - lensrch > MAXLIN - 1) {
                    fputs ("error: replaced length would exeed size.\n",
                            stderr);
                    return;
                }
                if (!p[lenword]) {          /* if no following char */
                    memcpy (p, repl, lenrepl);  /* just copy replace */
                    p[lenrepl] = 0;             /* and nul-terminate */
                }
                else {  /* store rest of line in buffer, replace, add end */
                    char endbuf[MAXLIN];    /* temp buffer for end */
                    size_t lenend = strlen (p + lensrch);   /* end length */
                    memcpy (endbuf, p + lensrch, lenend + 1); /* copy end */
                    memcpy (p, repl, lenrepl);  /* make replacement */
                    memcpy (p + lenrepl, endbuf, lenend); /* add end after */
                }
            }
            else {  /* otherwise replace is shorter than search */
                size_t lenend = strlen (p + lenword);   /* get end length */
                memcpy (p, repl, lenrepl);              /* copy replace */
                /* move end to after replace */
                memmove (p + lenrepl, p + lenword, lenend + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char str[MAXLIN] = "apple tree house in the elm tree";
    const char  *search = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "tree",
                *replace = argc > 2 ? argv[2] : "12",
                *delim = " \t\n";

    wordreplace (str, search, replace, delim);

    printf ("str: %s\n", str);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Your replace `"tree"` with `"12"` example in `"apple tree house in the elm tree"`:

```
$ ./bin/wordrepl_strstr_strcspn
str: apple 12 house in the elm 12
```

A simple same-length replacement of `"tree"` with `"core"`, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/wordrepl_strstr_strcspn tree core
str: apple core house in the elm core
```

The "longer than" replacemnt of `"tree"` with `"bobbing"`:

```
$ ./bin/wordrepl_strstr_strcspn tree bobbing
str: apple bobbing house in the elm bobbing
```

There are many different ways you can approach this problem, so no one way is the right way. The key is to make it understandable and reasonably efficient. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid `strtok` in this case (because it will modify the string as a side effect of tokenizing it), and approach this by looking at the string essentially character-by-character and maintaining a "read" and "write" index. Because the output can never be longer than the input, the write index will never get ahead of the read one, and you can "write-back" and make the change within the same string.

To visualize this, I find it useful to write out the input in boxes and draw arrows to current read and write indexes and track through the process so you can verify that you have a system that will do what you want it to do and that your loops and indexes all work like you expect.

Here is one implementation that matches how my own mind tends to approach this sort of algorithm. It walks the string and looks ahead to try matching from the current character. If it finds a match, it copies the replace onto the current spot, and increments both indexes accordingly.

```
void wordreplace(char * string, const char * search, const char * replace) {

    // This is required to be true since we're going to do the replace
    // in-place:
    assert(strlen(replace) <= strlen(search)); 

    // Get ourselves set up
    int r = 0, w = 0; 
    int str_len = strlen(string);
    int search_len = strlen(search);
    int replace_len = strlen(replace);

    // Walk through the input character by character.
    while (r < str_len) {

        // Is this character the start of a matching token? It is
        // if we see the search string followed by a space or end of
        // string. 
        if (strncmp(&string[r], search, search_len) == 0 &&
            (string[r+search_len] == ' ' || string[r+search_len] == '\0')) { 

            // We matched the search token. Copy the replace token.
            memcpy(&string[w], replace, replace_len);

            // Update our indexes.
            w += replace_len;
            r += search_len;
        } else {
            // Otherwise just copy this character.
            string[w++] = string[r++];
        }
    }

    // Be sure to terminate the final version of the string.
    string[w] = '\0';
}
```

(Note that I tweaked your function signature to use the more idiomatic pointer notation rather than char arrays, and per flu's comment below, I marked the search and replace tokens as "const" which is a way of the function advertising that it will not modify those strings.)

Comment: `search` and `replace` should be `const char *`

Comment: another minor suggest: replace `strcpy` with `memcpy` to avoid the unnecessary insertion of null char.

Comment: This seems to have trouble with a replacement term of equal or greater length than the search term.

Comment: @flu: Thanks, not just unncessary but also incorrect here for some cases. Fixed.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks, FYI per OP's clarification in comments (and edit), the greater-length case isn't actually (I think?) part of the problem space here.  Agree that it opens a whole other algorithmic can of worms if it were and this approach is insufficient without at least creating an additional temp buffer of.. some unknowable length.

Comment: No worries, I wasn't entirely clear on what all his constraints were. I was just messing around running your code (I like it) and tried it with several variation of the replacement.